# How can i delete a java file with out using task in gradle script?

Tags: gradle

How can I Delete a java file inside a jar folder by Gradle script with out using task?

i tried like this **delete 'the path of the file where it is getting stored'**
but it didn't get deleted. can any one help please

Comment: How did the java file get into the jar folder - surely easier to stop it getting there during the build

Comment: can you pls teach me how can that be possible pls... @Mark

Comment: How dod the file get there?

Comment: i'm having 4 java files in one folder in from those i'm executing only two and these executed files are saved as class files in jar folder but other two java files are getting into the jar folder- @ Mark

Comment: Gradel should be compiling java files not executing - you need to make the question clearer and perhaps show the gradle script and if not using default explain why. However given you have answers here that should be a separate question

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html:

> You can locate a file relative to the project directory using the Project.file() method.

The file() method returns an instance of [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html), which has a delete() method.
So you simply need

```
file("the/path/of/the/file").delete()
```

Comment: file("the/path/of/the/file").deleteDir() will even delete non-empty directories. deleteDir() is an enhanced Groovy method that is not available in the Java File class.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the java file api way of deleting a file as JB explained, Gradle also provides a method for that. you can use `Project#delete(Object...)`instead.

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:delete(java.lang.Object...)

for the details